# Is the Time object suitable to create a calendar?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I want to make a database-backed calendar. Will the Time object make my life easier? It hasn't so far...

#### The `.end_of_year` method gives me some strange information.

If it's contemporary time it works flawlessly:

```
date = '2012-3-2'.to_time(:utc) #=>  2012-03-02 00:00:00 UTC 
date.end_of_year #=> 2012-12-31 23:59:59 UTC
```

However, if you go back in time things get strange.

```
date = '1399-3-2'.to_time(:utc) #=> 1399-03-02 00:00:00 UTC 
date.end_of_year #=> 1399-12-23 23:59:59 UTC
```

23rd of December? Shouldn't that be 31st?

It's not even consistent:

```
date = '0000-3-2'.to_time(:utc) #=> 0000-03-02 00:00:00 UTC 
date.end_of_year #=> 0001-01-02 23:59:59 UTC
```

Um, the 2nd of January? OF THE NEXT YEAR? What is going on?

**Also, are leap years taken into account by the object?**

Comment: Did the concept of January 2nd even exist in the year 0?

Comment: Don't know. Maybe, it's called the Roman Calendar after all :P. Obviously I'm not going to use these dates, but it's a bit weird, isn't it? I'd like to know why. And what if someone wanted to make a historical timeline on their website?

Comment: I edited you're question. You're apparently using `Time` not `Date`. Also added the Rails tag, because all these methods are not standard Ruby methods. They are added by Rails.

Comment: Any utc date before `Epoch*=(1 January 1970 (or 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z ISO 8601))` would most likely result in an error as `UTC` did not exist in its current form until 1972, you can read up http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time for better understanding

Comment: @bjhaid Ah I see, that makes a lot of sense. I just want peace of mind before I plough into this project so that's cleared it up! What about things such as leap years? Do you know if all of that is taken into account?

Comment: Yes, leap year are taken into account: `'1980-02-01'.to_time(:utc).end_of_month # => 1980-02-29 23:59:59 UTC`. Leap years in the future too: `'2016-02-01'.to_time(:utc).end_of_month # => 2016-02-29 23:59:59 UTC`. Even leap years in the next millennium: `'3004-02-01'.to_time(:utc).end_of_month # => 3004-02-29 23:59:59 UTC`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use DateTime instead:

```
date = '2012-3-2'.to_datetime #=> Fri, 02 Mar 2012 00:00:00 +0000
date.end_of_year #=> Mon, 31 Dec 2012 23:59:59 +0000

date = '1399-3-2'.to_datetime #=> Sun, 02 Mar 1399 00:00:00 +0000
date.end_of_year #=> Wed, 31 Dec 1399 23:59:59 +0000 

date = '0000-3-2'.to_datetime #=> Tue, 02 Mar 0000 00:00:00 +0000 
date.end_of_year #=> Fri, 31 Dec 0000 23:59:59 +0000
```

It's mora accurate, and you can format the output

Answer (score 1):

I've did some digging. Here's what I found.

Let's begin with [end_of_year](http://apidock.com/rails/DateAndTime/Calculations/end_of_year):

```
def end_of_year
  change(:month => 12).end_of_month
end
```

Which relies on `change` and [end_of_month](http://apidock.com/rails/DateAndTime/Calculations/end_of_month):

```
def end_of_month
  last_day = ::Time.days_in_month(month, year)
  last_hour{ days_since(last_day - day) }
end
```

The most interesting part is happening inside of [days_since](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/DateAndTime/Calculations/days_since):

```
def days_since(days)
  advance(:days => days)
end
```

The [advance](http://apidock.com/rails/Time/advance) method is a bit more complex:

```
def advance(options)
  unless options[:weeks].nil?
    options[:weeks], partial_weeks = options[:weeks].divmod(1)
    options[:days] = options.fetch(:days, 0) + 7 * partial_weeks
  end

  unless options[:days].nil?
    options[:days], partial_days = options[:days].divmod(1)
    options[:hours] = options.fetch(:hours, 0) + 24 * partial_days
  end

  d = to_date.advance(options)
  time_advanced_by_date = change(:year => d.year, :month => d.month, :day => d.day)
  seconds_to_advance =        options.fetch(:seconds, 0) +
    options.fetch(:minutes, 0) * 60 +
    options.fetch(:hours, 0) * 3600

  if seconds_to_advance.zero?
    time_advanced_by_date
  else
    time_advanced_by_date.since(seconds_to_advance)
  end
end
```

And ***he is the guy we're looking for*** :

```
# in rails console
time = '0000-01-01'.to_time(:utc)  #=> 0000-01-01 00:00:00 UTC
time.advance(days: 1)              #=> 0000-01-04 00:00:00 UTC
time.advance(days: 2)              #=> 0000-01-05 00:00:00 UTC
time.advance(days: 3)              #=> 0000-01-06 00:00:00 UTC
```

That's all for now. I will continue to dig.